# Error when trying to run npm start command

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd, npm-start

I am trying to create a react project i have run npx create-react-app hello-react --use-npm then cd hello-react but when I've npm start this error has been shown:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\develompent\Desktop\react\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\develompent\Desktop\react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\develompent\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-30T18_43_59_773Z-debug.log

C:\Users\develompent\Desktop\react>cd hello-react

C:\Users\develompent\Desktop\react\hello-react>npm start

> hello-react@0.1.0 start C:\Users\develompent\Desktop\react\hello-react
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.137.1/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\develompent\Desktop\react\hello-react\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn powershell',
  path: 'powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBgACIAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAA6ADMAMAAwADAAYAAiACIA'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\develompent\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-30T18_44_47_550Z-debug.log
```

i have tried to to delete the node_modules  then I've installed it another time but the same issue still happening
and I also  tried to run the cmd as an administrator but it did not open without showing any errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

downgrade react scripts for project with these commands

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder and try with this:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

You’ll need to have Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine

> https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall node in the path `C:\windows\System32`

or you can

Follow these steps:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- delete `node_modules` folder
- delete `package-lock.json` file
- `npm install`